# Node glob isn't matching anything if path starts with "./" and nocase: true - bug or expected?

Tags: node.js, debugging, glob, case-insensitive

Reproduction instructions:

Starting from an empty directory I created a `package.json`:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "glob": "7.1.1"
    }
}
```

7.1.1 is the latest version at the time of editing this post. I then ran `npm install` and finally the `node` command:

```
> var glob = require('glob');
undefined
> glob.sync('*');
[ 'node_modules', 'package.json' ]
> glob.sync('./*');
[ './node_modules', './package.json' ]
```

That all makes sense, but here's where it gets weird:

```
> glob.sync('*', { nocase: true });
[ 'node_modules', 'package.json' ]
> glob.sync('./*', { nocase: true });
[]
```

I thought `nocase` should only affect case sensitivity. I can't see anything in the documentation and I couldn't find any Google results to explain this behaviour.

Is this a bug or does this make sense in a way that I don't currently understand?

Comment: Still problematic one and a half years later. I've pointed to this question on a potentially relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/161 - will keep posted.

Comment: thank you for debugging and raising this issue!  i was going crazy trying to figure out why glob was sometimes giving empty results for me

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem today and I found an issue on github. It even provides a possible solution for your problem. Unfortunately, the solution isn't as clean as one would hope.

Link: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1144

Comment: Thanks for the link, but while they seem to think it's resolved, this issue is still occurring.